# Two odbc_connect calls using the same credentials

Tags: php, odbc

What happens when two odbc_connect calls are made using the same credentials?

To be more specific with my question,

- Will there be two connections active, or will both resources be
  references to the same connection?
- Do the second connection take place if there already is a connection
  with the same credentials?

  ```
  <?php
      $user     = "root";
      $password = "root";
      $server   = "localhost";
      $db       = "dbo";

      $dsn      = "SERVER=$server; DRIVER=SQL Server; DATABASE=$db";

      $connection_1 = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
      //Do some stuff
      $connection_2 = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
      //Do some stuff
  ?>
  ```

The reason I ask is because I have a class that encapsulates the whole connection process, and there are separate php docs that are then included, each with their own instance of the class, each making a connection attempt with the same credentials when instantiated. Which would mean, if I had 3 instances, there would be 3 connection attempts with the same credentials.

I solved this by using a static property for the link, and check if the link is already used before attempting to connect again, but I'm still curious as to what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test of this using MySQL GUI tools and I tried your concept (ODBC to MySQL). At least with the case of MySQL, it did create two distinct connections.

Answer (score 0):

I used PHP 5.2 and ODBC for connecting to MSSQL and it did not create distinct connections. Actually - when I closed one connection open the other got closed too, so possibly they were distinct but all closed together by a bug.